# zsh: command not found: solc (macOS Monterey)

Tags: python, solc

Installed `solc` with this command:

```
% pip3 install solc-select
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: solc-select in /Users/test2/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pycryptodome>=3.4.6 in /Users/test2/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from solc-select) (3.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /Users/test2/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from solc-select) (22.0)
```

When launch:

```
% solc --version          
zsh: command not found: solc
```

Any thoughts why this happens?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the path of the binary to the `PATH` environment variable using the command:

1. `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/test2/Library/Python/3.9/bin/`
2. `solc-select` or `solc` ....

If you don't want to type `export` command everytime you open a new terminal, you can add that to the file `~/.zshrc`:

1. `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/Users/test2/Library/Python/3.9/bin/' >> ~/.zshrc`
2. Open a new terminal and use `solc-select`